# Django test case raises OperationalError - CREATE command denied

Tags: python, django

I have read the TestCase module from Django Docs and I tried to use this in my django project. However I got an eror like this:

**

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hp/.virtualenvs/shouchela/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1026, in setUpClass
    if not connections_support_transactions():
  File "/home/hp/.virtualenvs/shouchela/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 991, in connections_support_transactions
    for conn in connections.all())
  File "/home/hp/.virtualenvs/shouchela/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 991, in <genexpr>
    for conn in connections.all())
  File "/home/hp/.virtualenvs/shouchela/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/hp/.virtualenvs/shouchela/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/features.py", line 226, in supports_transactions
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE ROLLBACK_TEST (X INT)')
  File "/home/hp/.virtualenvs/shouchela/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hp/.virtualenvs/shouchela/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hp/.virtualenvs/shouchela/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/hp/.virtualenvs/shouchela/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/hp/.virtualenvs/shouchela/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 112, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/hp/.virtualenvs/shouchela/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/hp/.virtualenvs/shouchela/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (1142, "CREATE command denied to user 'xxxx'@'xxx' for table 'ROLLBACK_TEST'")
```

**

This is my code:

```
import os
import socket
import sys

hostname = socket.gethostname()
SETTINGS_DICT = {
    'slave': "shouchela.settings.chewantest",
    'master': "shouchela.settings.dev",
}
SETTINGS = SETTINGS_DICT.get(hostname, "shouchela.settings.dev")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", SETTINGS)

parent = lambda path, count: parent(os.path.dirname(path), count - 1) if count > 0 else path
sys.path.insert(0, parent(os.path.abspath(__file__), 2))

reload(sys)

sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

import django
django.setup()
from django.test import TestCase

class WebOpsTest(TestCase):
    def test_search(self):
        response = self.client.get('/ops/car/search/')
        print response
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong in my code? How to solve it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like a database permissions issue. Check permissions on ROLLBACK_TEST

Comment: When you try to use Django TestCase module, it create Database in your Database by default.So, you have "create" permission.I don't have this permission,so I got this error. I change local database, and problem was be  solved.